# How to include external CDN library?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, gsap

I had tried placing

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

everywhere in my code and it wont works. I've seen quite a few post that had the same issue but most of them said placing the cdn right before  but it still doesn't work for me. I had tried downloading the gsap.min.js file and put it in the same folder as my html file and it also wont work. I am using Visual Studio Code. But before this i am using Codepen and everthing works just fine.
This is my full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wheel</title>
</head>

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let circles = gsap.utils.toArray([".c1", ".c2", ".c3", ".c4", ".c5", ".c6", ".c7", ".c8", ".c9"]),
            angleIncrement = 360 / circles.length;


        circles.forEach(function(circle, index) {

            circle.addEventListener("click", function() {

                gsap.to(".wheel", {
                    rotation: (index * angleIncrement) + "_short",
                    duration: 1,
                    ease: "power1.inOut"
                });
            });
        });


        let bounds = document.querySelector(".st0").getBBox();
        gsap.set(".wheel", {
            svgOrigin: (bounds.x + bounds.width / 2) + " " + (bounds.y + bounds.height / 2)
        });



        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.circle').click(function() {
                var relation = $(this).data('relation');
                var squareReltedToClick = $("#content").find('#' + relation);
                $('.sq').removeClass('active');
                squareReltedToClick.addClass('active');
                var bgColor = $(this).css('fill');
                $('.sq').css('background-color', bgColor);
            });
        });
    </script>


    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 470 467" style="enable-background:new 0 0 470 467;" xml:space="preserve">
<g class="wheel">
       <path class="st0" d="M304,234c0,12.2-3.26,23.64-8.97,33.5c-1.96,3.39-4.21,6.59-6.7,9.57c-7.5,8.92-17.27,15.85-28.41,19.9
           c-3.62,1.32-7.4,2.34-11.28,3.02c-3.78,0.66-7.68,1.01-11.64,1.01c-8.05,0-15.77-1.42-22.92-4.03c-3.69-1.34-7.23-3-10.58-4.95
           c-10.17-5.87-18.65-14.35-24.53-24.52c-1.94-3.35-3.6-6.89-4.94-10.58c-2.61-7.15-4.03-14.87-4.03-22.92
           c0-3.97,0.34-7.85,1.01-11.63c0.68-3.89,1.7-7.66,3.02-11.29c4.05-11.15,10.99-20.92,19.9-28.4c2.98-2.51,6.18-4.76,9.57-6.71
           c9.85-5.71,21.29-8.97,33.5-8.97c3.97,0,7.86,0.34,11.64,1.01c11.83,2.07,22.6,7.25,31.43,14.67c2.99,2.51,5.75,5.27,8.25,8.26
           c7.42,8.83,12.6,19.59,14.67,31.43C303.66,226.15,304,230.03,304,234z"/>
       <g id="stick9">
           <line id="wheel" class="st1" x1="332.76" y1="314.35" x2="288.33" y2="277.07"/>
           <circle id="wheel" class="st1 c9 circle" data-relation="square9" cx="371.06" cy="346.49" r="50"/>
       </g>
       <g id="stick8">
           <line id="wheel" class="st2" x1="258.71" y1="357.1" x2="248.64" y2="299.99"/>
           <circle id="wheel" class="st2 c8 circle" data-relation="square8" cx="267.39" cy="406.34" r="50"/>
       </g>
       <g id="stick7">
           <line id="wheel" class="st3" x1="203.5" y1="292.02" x2="174.5" y2="342.25"/>
           <circle id="wheel" class="st3 c7 circle" data-relation="square7" cx="149.5" cy="385.55" r="50"/>
       </g>
       <g id="stick6">
           <line id="wheel" class="st4" x1="174.03" y1="256.92" x2="119.54" y2="276.75"/>
           <circle id="wheel" class="st4 c6 circle" data-relation="square6" cx="72.55" cy="293.85" r="50"/>
       </g>
       <g id="stick5">
           <line id="wheel" class="st5" x1="174.03" y1="211.08" x2="119.54" y2="191.25"/>
           <circle id="wheel" class="st5 c5 circle" data-relation="square5" cx="72.55" cy="174.15" r="50"/>
       </g>
       <g>
           <line id="wheel" class="st6" x1="203.5" y1="175.97" x2="174.5" y2="125.75"/>
           <circle id="wheel" class="st6 c4 circle" data-relation="square4" cx="149.5" cy="82.45" r="50"/>
       </g>
       <g id="stick3">
           <line id="wheel" class="st7" x1="258.71" y1="110.9" x2="248.64" y2="168.01"/>
           <circle id="wheel" class="st7 c3 circle" data-relation="square3" cx="267.39" cy="61.66" r="50"/>
       </g>
       <g id="stick2">
           <line id="wheel" class="st8" x1="332.76" y1="153.65" x2="288.32" y2="190.94"/>
           <circle id="wheel" class="st8 c2 circle" data-relation="square2" cx="371.06" cy="121.51" r="50"/>
       </g>
       <g id="stick1">
           <line id="wheel" class="st9" x1="362" y1="234" x2="304" y2="234"/>
           <circle id="wheel" class="st9 c1 circle" data-relation="square1" cx="412" cy="234" r="50"/>
       </g>
</g>

</svg>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="content1 sq active" id="square1">1</div>
        <div class="content2 sq" id="square2">2</div>
        <div class="content3 sq" id="square3">3</div>
        <div class="content4 sq" id="square4">4</div>
        <div class="content5 sq" id="square5">5</div>
        <div class="content6 sq" id="square6">6</div>
        <div class="content7 sq" id="square7">7</div>
        <div class="content8 sq" id="square8">8</div>
        <div class="content9 sq" id="square9">9</div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As soon as you use `$()`  in your code, jQuery must already be loaded. Move the jQuery script above your own script (or put it in <head>).

Comment: I always place it at the head. It works for me, what problem does it give?

Comment: @Abhishek It does not give any error but the SVG should have animation. I had tried moving it to the head but it did not work too.

Comment: GSAP has [a great installation page](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation) with videos and copy/paste-able code that can help you get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your external libraries before you use them. For example, place the included script tags before the other javascript! This way the jquery won't be invalid! Put them in your header or before the other javascript!

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: There's nothing wrong whatsoever helping other people. You could have done that in the comments as well, though!

Answer (score 1):

Libraries need to be hooked up to your main JavaScript code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wheel</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 470 467" style="enable-background:new 0 0 470 467;" xml:space="preserve">
      <g class="wheel">
        <path class="st0" d="M304,234c0,12.2-3.26,23.64-8.97,33.5c-1.96,3.39-4.21,6.59-6.7,9.57c-7.5,8.92-17.27,15.85-28.41,19.9
           c-3.62,1.32-7.4,2.34-11.28,3.02c-3.78,0.66-7.68,1.01-11.64,1.01c-8.05,0-15.77-1.42-22.92-4.03c-3.69-1.34-7.23-3-10.58-4.95
           c-10.17-5.87-18.65-14.35-24.53-24.52c-1.94-3.35-3.6-6.89-4.94-10.58c-2.61-7.15-4.03-14.87-4.03-22.92
           c0-3.97,0.34-7.85,1.01-11.63c0.68-3.89,1.7-7.66,3.02-11.29c4.05-11.15,10.99-20.92,19.9-28.4c2.98-2.51,6.18-4.76,9.57-6.71
           c9.85-5.71,21.29-8.97,33.5-8.97c3.97,0,7.86,0.34,11.64,1.01c11.83,2.07,22.6,7.25,31.43,14.67c2.99,2.51,5.75,5.27,8.25,8.26
           c7.42,8.83,12.6,19.59,14.67,31.43C303.66,226.15,304,230.03,304,234z" />
        <g id="stick9">
          <line id="wheel" class="st1" x1="332.76" y1="314.35" x2="288.33" y2="277.07" />
          <circle id="wheel" class="st1 c9 circle" data-relation="square9" cx="371.06" cy="346.49" r="50" />
        </g>
        <g id="stick8">
          <line id="wheel" class="st2" x1="258.71" y1="357.1" x2="248.64" y2="299.99" />
          <circle id="wheel" class="st2 c8 circle" data-relation="square8" cx="267.39" cy="406.34" r="50" />
        </g>
        <g id="stick7">
          <line id="wheel" class="st3" x1="203.5" y1="292.02" x2="174.5" y2="342.25" />
          <circle id="wheel" class="st3 c7 circle" data-relation="square7" cx="149.5" cy="385.55" r="50" />
        </g>
        <g id="stick6">
          <line id="wheel" class="st4" x1="174.03" y1="256.92" x2="119.54" y2="276.75" />
          <circle id="wheel" class="st4 c6 circle" data-relation="square6" cx="72.55" cy="293.85" r="50" />
        </g>
        <g id="stick5">
          <line id="wheel" class="st5" x1="174.03" y1="211.08" x2="119.54" y2="191.25" />
          <circle id="wheel" class="st5 c5 circle" data-relation="square5" cx="72.55" cy="174.15" r="50" />
        </g>
        <g>
          <line id="wheel" class="st6" x1="203.5" y1="175.97" x2="174.5" y2="125.75" />
          <circle id="wheel" class="st6 c4 circle" data-relation="square4" cx="149.5" cy="82.45" r="50" />
        </g>
        <g id="stick3">
          <line id="wheel" class="st7" x1="258.71" y1="110.9" x2="248.64" y2="168.01" />
          <circle id="wheel" class="st7 c3 circle" data-relation="square3" cx="267.39" cy="61.66" r="50" />
        </g>
        <g id="stick2">
          <line id="wheel" class="st8" x1="332.76" y1="153.65" x2="288.32" y2="190.94" />
          <circle id="wheel" class="st8 c2 circle" data-relation="square2" cx="371.06" cy="121.51" r="50" />
        </g>
        <g id="stick1">
          <line id="wheel" class="st9" x1="362" y1="234" x2="304" y2="234" />
          <circle id="wheel" class="st9 c1 circle" data-relation="square1" cx="412" cy="234" r="50" />
        </g>
      </g>

    </svg>

    <div id="content">
      <div class="content1 sq active" id="square1">1</div>
      <div class="content2 sq" id="square2">2</div>
      <div class="content3 sq" id="square3">3</div>
      <div class="content4 sq" id="square4">4</div>
      <div class="content5 sq" id="square5">5</div>
      <div class="content6 sq" id="square6">6</div>
      <div class="content7 sq" id="square7">7</div>
      <div class="content8 sq" id="square8">8</div>
      <div class="content9 sq" id="square9">9</div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let circles = gsap.utils.toArray([".c1", ".c2", ".c3", ".c4", ".c5", ".c6", ".c7", ".c8", ".c9"]),
        angleIncrement = 360 / circles.length;


      circles.forEach(function(circle, index) {

        circle.addEventListener("click", function() {

          gsap.to(".wheel", {
            rotation: (index * angleIncrement) + "_short",
            duration: 1,
            ease: "power1.inOut"
          });
        });
      });


      let bounds = document.querySelector(".st0").getBox();
      gsap.set(".wheel", {
        svgOrigin: (bounds.x + bounds.width / 2) + " " + (bounds.y + bounds.height / 2)
      });



      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.circle').click(function() {
          var relation = $(this).data('relation');
          var squareReltedToClick = $("#content").find('#' + relation);
          $('.sq').removeClass('active');
          squareReltedToClick.addClass('active');
          var bgColor = $(this).css('fill');
          $('.sq').css('background-color', bgColor);
        });
      });

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your script tag in head tag before using it.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wheel</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: This is misinformation, there's no *need* to put it in the `head` - it just needs to be before it is used.

Comment: @freedomn-m, you should not term it as "misinformation", it is one of the way out of many ways. I hope you get my point.